# Solving graph coloring problem using genetic algorithms

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithms, colorings

I have some basic information about the graph coloring problem, which is an **NP-Complete** problem.

I am very new to genetic algorithms, and I have faced a problem in which we have to solve the graph coloring problem using genetic algorithms.
I have seen this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hu0Xf1HqBXw), and also I have read the explanation which has been provided in this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/project-idea-genetic-algorithms-for-graph-colouring/#:%7E:text=Graph%20Coloring%20is%20about%20minimizing,coloring%20using%20k%2D1%20colors.).

Here is my graph:

[image: Graph]

I can divide this problem into four parts.

1. How to `initialize the population` and create it, and define an `encoding` for our problem. (suppose that the size of the primary population is `6`)
2. How to calculate the `fitness` for every `chromosome` (a member of our population), and then sort the members base on their fitness value.
3. Perform `mutation` and `crossover` procedures on our primary population for creating a new one.
4. Now calculate the fitness values for our new population, and compare them with the old one.

I will be grateful for your help and advice. My problem is not about the code and the practical part, but an explanation of how to perform these steps on the above graph.

Comment: If you want to solve the coloring problem on this particular graph, a genetic algorithm seems a bit overkill: since the graph is planar, it is [4-colorable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem). An [exact algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Exact_algorithms) would also find the solution quickly enough.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is not an optimal solution, but I have to solve this problem only by genetic algorithm step by step. If you can provide a simpler example of implementing those four steps, I will be grateful.@Nathaniel

Comment: This sounds very straightforward. Can you clarify exactly what the issue is? If you just read a description of a genetic algorithm, you should be able to figure out the answers.

Comment: I don't know how to use it for solving a graph coloring problem, if you have an example with the above steps, may you send it please?.@Juho

Comment: I'm afraid that's not specific enough. We're here to help you understand but we're not solving your homework for you.

Comment: Ok, there is no problem. I will be grateful only for some explanation about how to determine a chromosome, and fitness in a simpler graph coloring problem, because I have no idea how to define a chromosome, and then implement crossover and mutation on it.@Juho